# why sudo -s 'printf "xx"' cannot handle newline?

Tags: bash, shell, newline

When calling the following command directly, the newline can be printed correctly.

```
printf "abc
def"
```

But when calling it with sudo -s, the newline is ignored.

```
sudo -s "printf 'abc
def'"
```

The $SHELL is using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be `sudo` removing line feeds. If you try to run the same command in a new bash instance, the line feed is still there:

```
bash -c "printf 'abc
def'"
```

Comment: Yes, but when you use "\n" or "\r\n", sudo -s can also print it correctly, how is press enter different with "\n"? I though in unix press enter is the same as "\n"

Comment: If you use `\n`, sudo will see two characters, `<backslash><n>`, and that will later be interpreted by `printf` as a line feed. But if you put a line feed in the string, sudo will see it as a line feed, and remove it.